# Spring Data 3.0.5 MongoDB and ElasticSearch Domain Class mixed Annotation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm migrating our application from Spring Boot 1.5.9 to version 2.0.0.

In version 1.5.9 we have successfully used mixed Annotations on several Domain Classes e.g:

```java
...
@org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document(collection = "folder")
@org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document(indexName = "folder")
public class Folder {
    ...
}
```

The same approach causes probems in Spring Boot 2.0.0. When MongoDB annotatnion **@DBRef** is used, Spring throws exception while ElasticsearchRepository creation:

```java
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No association found!
```

Here comes classes and confs

pom.xml

```xml
   ...
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springfrsamework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    ...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.18</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    ...
```

Application.java

```java
...
@EnableMongoRepositories("com.hydra.sbmr.repoMongo")
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories("com.hydra.sbmr.repoElastic")
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Folder.java (**Note this @DBRef couses exception**)

```java
package com.hydra.sbmr.model;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.DBRef;

@org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document(collection = "folder")
@org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document(indexName = "folder")
public class Folder {

    @Id
    @Getter @Setter private String id;

    // Why MongoDB core mapping @DBRef causes java.lang.IllegalStateException: No association found! exception
    // while ElasticsearchRepository creation???
    @DBRef
    @Getter @Setter private Profile profile;

    @Getter @Setter private String something;

}
```

Profile.java

```java
package com.hydra.sbmr.model;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

@org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document(collection = "profile")
public class Profile {

    @Id
    @Getter @Setter private String id;

    @Getter @Setter String blah;

}
```

FolderElasticRepository.java

```java
package com.hydra.sbmr.repoElastic;

import com.hydra.sbmr.model.Folder;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;

public interface FolderElasticRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Folder, String> {

}
```

You can find whole mini project on GitHub: https://github.com/hydraesb/sbmr

My question:

- Is there any solution that will work with mixed Annotatnions on Domain Classes (mongo and elastic) in Spring Boot 2.0.0???

Comment: Could you find any solution?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue and the solution that i found is to extends SimpleElasticsearchMappingContext like this :

```
    package com.mypackage;

    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
    import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate;
    import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.EntityMapper;
    import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter;
    import org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;

    import java.io.IOException;

    @Configuration
    public class ElasticsearchConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate(Client client, Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder) {
            return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client, new MappingElasticsearchConverter(new CustomElasticsearchMappingContext()),
                new CustomEntityMapper(jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.createXmlMapper(false).build()));
        }

        public class CustomEntityMapper implements EntityMapper {

            private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

            public CustomEntityMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
                this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
                objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
                objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
            }

            @Override
            public String mapToString(Object object) throws IOException {
                return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
            }

            @Override
            public  T mapToObject(String source, Class clazz) throws IOException {
                return objectMapper.readValue(source, clazz);
            }
        }
    }

    package com.mypackage;

    import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.mapping.ElasticsearchPersistentProperty;
    import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.mapping.SimpleElasticsearchMappingContext;
    import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.mapping.SimpleElasticsearchPersistentEntity;
    import org.springframework.data.mapping.model.Property;
    import org.springframework.data.mapping.model.SimpleTypeHolder;

    public class CustomElasticsearchMappingContext extends SimpleElasticsearchMappingContext {
        @Override
        protected ElasticsearchPersistentProperty createPersistentProperty(Property property, SimpleElasticsearchPersistentEntity owner, SimpleTypeHolder simpleTypeHolder) {
            return new CustomElasticsearchPersistentProperty(property, owner, simpleTypeHolder);
        }
    }

    package com.mypackage;

    import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.mapping.ElasticsearchPersistentProperty;
    import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.mapping.SimpleElasticsearchPersistentProperty;
    import org.springframework.data.mapping.PersistentEntity;
    import org.springframework.data.mapping.model.Property;
    import org.springframework.data.mapping.model.SimpleTypeHolder;

    public class CustomElasticsearchPersistentProperty extends SimpleElasticsearchPersistentProperty {

        public CustomElasticsearchPersistentProperty(Property property, PersistentEntity owner, SimpleTypeHolder simpleTypeHolder) {
            super(property, owner, simpleTypeHolder);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAssociation() {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I also needed `@Bean public CustomElasticsearchMappingContext elasticsearchMappingContext() { return new CustomElasticsearchMappingContext(); }`.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem also and I fixed with solution of @ybouraze

```
@Bean
fun elasticsearchTemplate(client: JestClient, converter: ElasticsearchConverter, builder: Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder): ElasticsearchOperations {
    val entityMapper = CustomEntityMapper(builder.createXmlMapper(false).build())
    val mapper = DefaultJestResultsMapper(converter.mappingContext, entityMapper)
    return JestElasticsearchTemplate(client, converter, mapper)
}

@Bean
@Primary
fun mappingContext(): SimpleElasticsearchMappingContext {
    return MappingContext()
}

@Bean
fun elasticsearchConverter(): ElasticsearchConverter {
    return MappingElasticsearchConverter(mappingContext())
}

inner class CustomEntityMapper(private val objectMapper: ObjectMapper) : EntityMapper {

    init {
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true)
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun mapToString(`object`: Any): String {
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(`object`)
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun <T> mapToObject(source: String, clazz: Class<T>): T {
        return objectMapper.readValue(source, clazz)
    }
}

inner class MappingContext : SimpleElasticsearchMappingContext() {
    override fun createPersistentProperty(property: Property, owner: SimpleElasticsearchPersistentEntity<*>, simpleTypeHolder: SimpleTypeHolder): ElasticsearchPersistentProperty {
        return PersistentProperty(property, owner, simpleTypeHolder)
    }
}

inner class PersistentProperty(property: Property, owner: SimpleElasticsearchPersistentEntity<*>, simpleTypeHolder: SimpleTypeHolder) : SimpleElasticsearchPersistentProperty(property, owner, simpleTypeHolder) {
    override fun isAssociation(): Boolean {
        return false
    }
}
```